# search and remove specific file using linux command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command

I using this command for search all file contain this word . I want to remove all file contain this word in specific directory . grep command perfectly. suggest me how can I used

```
     rm -rf
```

with below command

```
     grep -l -r  -i  "Pending" . | grep -n  . | wc -l
```

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84852/delete-files-matching-pattern) Link will help you meet your requirements.

Comment: `grep -n` already shows line numbers, hhere's no need to pipe that to `wc -l`. To just obtain the count, omit the `grep`, or simply pipe to `grep -c` if you genuinely need to filter out empty lines (but in this case you really don't; `grep -l` could certainly emit file names which contain two consecutive newlines, but if you have file names with newlines, the rest of the pipeline is broken anyway).

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by using the `l` flag and piping the filenames to `xargs`:

> -l
>       (The letter ell.) Write only the names of files containing selected
>       lines to standard output. Pathnames are written once per file searched.
>       If the standard input is searched, a pathname of (standard input) will
>       be written, in the POSIX locale. In other locales, standard input may be
>       replaced by something more appropriate in those locales.

```
grep -l -r 'Pending' . | xargs rm
```

The above will delete all files in the current directory containing the word `Pending`.

Comment: output is given like this                                                                                                                          rm: cannot remove 'Scenario726EB519-D21E-DD8E-D632-339885A1FA58.html': No such file or directory

Comment: @MayureshHedaoo - Try to use the `-0` flag like: `xargs -0 rm`